# Why Laravel is checking CORS server side?

Tags: php, laravel, security, cors

Laravel uses the package, and the code is from `fruitcake/laravel-cors` version 1 (currently it uses version 2)

```
        // If the request is not allowed, return 403
        if (! $this->cors->isActualRequestAllowed($request)) {
            return new Response('Not allowed in CORS policy.', 403);
        }
```

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/blob/1d127dbec313e2e227d65e0c483765d8d7559bf6/src/HandleCors.php#L45

My question is why it's checking CORS server side?

Comment: CORS involve, not just the browser, but the server as well: the server must inspect preflight requests and decide what to do. Do you understand that?

Comment: @jub0bs Yes, but here if the request origin header is not equal to our origin it will return a 403 error with message of `Not allowed in CORS policy.`. AFAIK frontend (browser) should shows the error not backend! What am I miss?

Comment: @Ali, You’re not missing anything. Laravel doesn’t need to be doing that check, and doesn’t need to be returning a 403. It rightly should just be leaving it up the browser, because that’s how the CORS protocol works. That said, there’s nothing in the CORS spec that disallows server runtimes from doing something like this. But it’s completely unnecessary and it’s a bad idea in practice — because it can result in a lot of web-developer confusion when trying to debug CORS problems. So you’re right to call this out. IMHO, server runtimes doing this kind of stuff is a bad anti-pattern.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Good point. I should have looked more closely at the actual check.

Comment: there is no good answer to your question. Why ? because it can and it's an option. You dont like it ? disable it from your global middleware in kernel.php.